# SAS Pass-Through rows affected

Tags: sas

I'm trying with following SAS code:

```
proc sql;
connect to oracle as oracle(&user &pass &path);
  execute(delete from t where x > 1) by oracle;
disconnect from oracle;
quit;
```

And eventually I need to print to the log file how many rows were deleted.

For now I've found two macro variables `SQLXRC` and `SQLXMSG`, however they represent only return code and error message accordingly. That's not enough to get the desired.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a question about how to use ORACLE, not SAS.

Comment: @Tom if it would be possible using sql%rowcount, that might have been a solution

Comment: Is there a way to return the value of sql%rowcount as part of a query?  Or would you need to create a stored procedure to run the delete, save the count and then return the count as query result so that SAS could try to run the procedure as part of a select rather than execute statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the equivalent query and return the results before executing the delete:

Also, the `as oracle` bit is not needed, you can use the `as` keyword in the `connect to` statement to assign an alias, which is the name of the engine (`oracle`) by default

```
proc sql noprint;
connect to oracle (&user &pass &path);
  select c into :ct from connection to oracle (select count(*) as c from t where x > 1);
  %PUT NOTE: There are &c rows in t where x > 1;
  execute(delete from t where x > 1) by oracle;
  %PUT NOTE: I deleted &c rows from t;
disconnect from oracle;
quit;
```

1. `NOPRINT` is used because otherwise the select statement prints the count to the output window
2. The `select ... from connection to` syntax allows results from a query to be returned to the SAS session.
3. The macro variable `c` is used to store the row count. The `INTO` clause in SAS followed by `:c` means load the results into a macro variable called `c`. You can check the value using `&c`.
4. `%PUT` statements are used to return information to the log.

If the table happened to change between execution of the two statements, then the select statement might not return an accurate count of the number of rows deleted.

Comment: Sorry for the amateur question, but what does _into :ct_ means ? I see it once in a while **select count(distinct product) into :ct **
. Could you help point to the documentation ?

Comment: If you search for `SAS SQL INTO Clause` then you'll get the documentation

Comment: Your example would create a macro variable called `ct` from the count of distinct product values returned from your query.

Comment: thanks @mjsqu. Is there any other scenarios where we use **:var_name** instead of **&var_name**

Comment: Not that I can think of, the colon in SAS is used to wildcard variable names, so `drop status: ;` will drop all columns called `status, status1, status_now` etc. It's also important to note that `&` is only ever used to recall, not assign a value, and `:` only used for assignment in `proc sql`